# How can i loop through 30 folders and create 4 subfolders in each by taking part of the name of the parent folder?

Tags: powershell

So I have 30 folders that all follow the same naming convention:

```
XXX-application name
```

the X's are numbers that are between 2 and 4 digits.
In the sub folders I need these folders created:

```
XXX-access mngt
XXX-app controls
XXX-support docs
XXX-vendor docs
```

I know how to code in Java but I have never used PowerShell (my mom needed help for her job) so I need some help, I did generate the parent folders with a script that takes the names from a text file.

I'd like some help with how to go about doing this, I do have a text file with the full name of each parent folder and a separate text file that just has the numbers of each

I haven't tried anything yet, this is the script I found/adapted to generate the parent folders (this works)

```
$folder="F:\Test\Folders"
$txtFile="F:\Test\MainFolder.txt"
$pattern="\d+.+"

get-content $txtFile | %{

    if($_ -match $pattern)
    {
        mkdir "$folder\$_"
    }
}
```

This took each line in the text file and made it into a folder

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '<path to parent folder>' -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        $parent = $_
        if($parent.Name -match '^(?<num>\d{2,4})-.*$') {
            "access mngt", "app controls", "support docs", "vendor docs" |
                ForEach-Object {
                    New-Item -Path $parent.FullName -Name "$($Matches.num)-$_" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
                }
        }
    }
```